# How to indexing JSONField inside NestedField in Django using django_elasticsearch_dsl?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-models

I have user model and comment, I am using django_elasticsearch_dsl to index in ElasticSearch

```
# models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  reply_type =  models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

`reply_type` content

```
reply_type: {
  "one": "on... ...",
  "two": "tw... ..."
}
```

Indexing to elastic I am doing it like this

```
# documents.py

@registry.register_document
class UserDocument(Document):
    email = fields.TextField()
    username = fields.TextField()
    first_name = fields.TextField()
    ...
    ...
    ...


    comment = fields.NestedField(properties={
        # other fields...
        'some_field': fields.TextField(),
        'reply_type': fields.ObjectField(),
    })    

    class Index:
        name = 'user'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0
        }

    class Django:
        model = User
```

The problem is that when I do the indexing the `reply_type` is empty

```
"reply_type": [
   { },
   { }
]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think this can help: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html

Answer (score 0):

Structure your reply_type ObjectField like this:

```
'reply_type': fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'one': fields.TextField(),
        'two': fields.TextField(),
})
```